# Does resetting std::shared_ptr lead to resetting its deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

maybe I misunderstood some aspects of smart pointers in c++, but after executing this code:

```
class cls
{
public:
    class deleter
    {
    public:
        const cls& obj;
        deleter(const cls& c) : obj(c) {}
        void operator()(int* num)
        {
            std::cout << "deleter was called" << std::endl;
            if (num)
            {
                std::cout << "num in deleter: " << *num << std::endl;
                if (*num == *obj.int_ptr)
                {
                    std::cout << "equal " << *num << " = " << *obj.int_ptr << std::endl;
                    delete num;
                }
                else
                    std::cout << "not equal" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    };

std::shared_ptr<int> int_ptr;
cls() : int_ptr(nullptr,deleter(*this)) {}
};

int main()
{
    cls obj;
    obj.int_ptr.reset(new int{15});
    return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
deleter was called

0
```

I noticed that reset() from shared_ptr removes custom deleter, that was passed to it in its constructor. On the contrary unique_ptr doesn't show such behavior, which seemed strange to me.

So what is going on here?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the STL.

Comment: @curiousguy the `std::shared_ptr` API isn't part of the STL?

Comment: @Spongman Absolutely not! The STL (Standard Template Library) is only loosely defined, but it *relates mainly to Containers and Iterators* and algorithm using iterators, and stuff specifically designed to work with those - as opposed to building blocks of general use. So while the frontier of what constitutes STL territory is ill defined, `std::shared_ptr` has no feature that would make it part of STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we assign the `nullptr` or call reset on std::shared_ptr, it will clear the pointer and getdeleter after cleaning memory. The way it is done for unique_ptr is different.

Below is the function from library which decrement the count of shared_ptr and if reference_count is zero then proceed with destruction:

```
void _Decref() noexcept { // decrement use count
    if (_MT_DECR(_Uses) == 0) {
        _Destroy();
        _Decwref();
    }
}
```

So, once you reset and reference _count is zero then  the shared_ptr the custom deleter will be removed due to reset.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`std::shared_ptr` stores the deleter inside the control block. So you can switch the deleter and use `std::shared_ptr` with large variety of deleters all the while sharing it with all other instances of the `std::shared_ptr` that point to the same data.

`std::unique_ptr` needs nothing of the sort and stores the deleter within its` instance when must. Also you have to specify usage of deleter as one of the template parameters.

Basically, in `std::shared_ptr` deleter is part of the data and in `std::unique_ptr` deleter is part of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The deleter is stored differently in the std::shared_ptr than it is in the std::unique_ptr. The std::unique_ptr uses empty base optimizations (EBO) to store the deleter which means the std::unique_ptr inherits the deleter. The std::shared_ptr does not do this, which is the why the deleter APIs are different between the two.